# XSLT template conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Our old code uses v1.0 xsl. I just changed it from :

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```

to:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
```

I am trying to check if any of illegal characters are present in the string using xsl.

This is how my code is doing it right now:

```
. . . 

<xsl:template match="GEN_Limit">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(.) &gt; 4">Limit ('<xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>') - may have up to 4 characters<br/> </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string-length(.) = 0">Limit is mandatory<br/></xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains((.),'!') or contains((.),'@') or contains((.),'#') or contains((.),'$') or contains((.),'%') or contains((.),'^') or contains((.),'&amp;') or contains((.),'*') or contains((.),'(') or contains((.),')')  or contains((.),'+')  or contains((.),'=') or contains((.),'{') or contains((.),'}') or contains((.),'[') or contains((.),']') or contains((.),'|') or contains((.),'\') or contains((.),':') or contains((.),';') or contains((.),'&lt;') or contains((.),'&gt;') or contains((.),'?') or contains((.),'/') or contains((.),',') or contains((.),'.')">Data entered - Limit('<xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>') may not have special characters <br/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GEN_AcctStationNumber">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(.) &gt; 6">Accounting Station Number('<xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>') - may have up to 6 characters
        <br/> </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string-length(.) = 0">Accounting Station Number is mandatory<br/></xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string(/Funding/FundsAgency) ='GEN' and not(string(/Funding/FundsFormCode) ='PP')">
        <xsl:if test="string(number(string(.) ) ) ='NaN'">Accounting Station Number must be numeric <br/> </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains((.),'!') or contains((.),'@') or contains((.),'#') or contains((.),'$') or contains((.),'%') or contains((.),'^') or contains((.),'&amp;') or contains((.),'*') or contains((.),'(') or contains((.),')')  or contains((.),'+')  or contains((.),'=') or contains((.),'{') or contains((.),'}') or contains((.),'[') or contains((.),']') or contains((.),'|') or contains((.),'\') or contains((.),':') or contains((.),';') or contains((.),'&lt;') or contains((.),'&gt;') or contains((.),'?') or contains((.),'/') or contains((.),',') or contains((.),'.')">Data entered - Accounting Station Number('<xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>') may not have special characters <br/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GEN_SupAcctClassification">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(.) &gt; 6">Supplemental Accounting Classification('<xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>') - may have up to 6 characters
        <br/> </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string-length(.) = 0">Supplemental Accounting Classification is mandatory<br/></xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string(/Funding/FundsAgency) ='GEN' and not(string(/Funding/FundsFormCode) ='PP')">
        <xsl:if test="string(number(string(.) ) ) ='NaN'">Supplemental Accounting Classification must be numeric <br/> </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains((.),'!') or contains((.),'@') or contains((.),'#') or contains((.),'$') or contains((.),'%') or contains((.),'^') or contains((.),'&amp;') or contains((.),'*') or contains((.),'(') or contains((.),')')  or contains((.),'+')  or contains((.),'=') or contains((.),'{') or contains((.),'}') or contains((.),'[') or contains((.),']') or contains((.),'|') or contains((.),'\') or contains((.),':') or contains((.),';') or contains((.),'&lt;') or contains((.),'&gt;') or contains((.),'?') or contains((.),'/') or contains((.),',') or contains((.),'.')">Data entered - Accounting Station Number('<xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>') may not have special characters <br/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

So you can see that `contains` is repeated everywhere, in 40 places to be exact. Is there a better way of doing this? Like using `matches`, maybe:

```
<xsl:variable name="illegalCharacters">! @ # $ % ^ &amp * ( ) \ + = { } [ | ] \ \ : ; &lt &gt ?  / , .</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="matches((.),$illegalCharacters)"></xsl:if>
```

Or even declare it at the top of the xml and make it usable everywhere since right now, I have that code repeat on 40 places for every template :/

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is your question tagged XSLT 1.0, if you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor? If you're not, why would you change the stylesheet's version?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I tag it v1.0 since I wasn't sure how to change from 1.0 to 2.0 or if I did it right

Comment: If your question is about XSLT 2.0, then the the XSLT 1.0 tag is irrelevant. There are simpler solutions for both versions, but regex is only available in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with `matches`

```
<xsl:if test="not(matches(., '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'))">
          Data entered - Accounting Station Number('<xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>') may not have special characters 
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @version should be either 1.0 or 2.0 or a variation, don't think there is a version 17

as for the `<xsl:if/>` tag, I'm guessing it falls in a template that matches a node along the lines of `<account-num/>`?

the `contains()` function, I don't think those parens are necessary

```
<xsl:if test="contains((.),'!') or 
          contains(.,'@') or   
          contains(.,'#')">
    Data entered - Account Number <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/> may 
    not have special characters <br/>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: I didn't notice version until you pointed it out :) thanks. yea that code is in every template.